# How to retrieve particular values from a list: python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of items

```
list = [{
            'id': '1',
            'elements': 'A',
            'table': 'path/to/table1',
            'chart': 'path/to/chart1',
        },
        {
            'id': '2',
            'elements': 'B',
            'table': 'path/to/table2',
            'chart': 'path/to/chart2',
        },
        {
            'id': '3',
            'elements': 'C',
            'table': 'path/to/table3',
            'chart': 'path/to/chart3',
        },]

selectionsFromTable = [{('A','2011','Table','Total'),
                       ('C','2011','Bar','Total'),
                       ('B','Pie','2001','Total')}]
```

Compare `list['elements']` with `selectionsFromTable` items and `if elem in selectionsFromTable == list['elements']` then append its respective table or chart to arr[].
Assume selectionsFromTable is form data getting from jquery. The index values and position of items always changes here.
i am doing this.

```
arr = []
for data in list:
    if data['elements'] in selectionsFromTable: # Suggest condition here
        inner = []
        if 'Table' in selectionsFromTable:
            print("table")
            inner.append({'id': data['id'],
                          'section_title': data['elements'],
                          'tableorChart': data['table'],
                          })

        elif 'Bar' in selectionsFromTable or 'Pie' in selectionsFromTable :
            print("chart")
            inner.append({'id': data['id'],
                          'section_title': data['elements'],
                          'tableorChart': data['chart'],
                          })

        arr.append(inner)
```

I believe it is wrong, kindly suggest me logic here. I am not able to go to "elif" condition as my selectionsFromTable contains "Table".

Comment: note that `data['elements']` is a string ('A', 'B', ...) and that the elements of `selectionsFromTable` are `dict` objects => you will never get inside the `if data['elements'] in selectionsFromTable:` condition.

Comment: how you want to compare `dict` type and `set` type elements?

Comment: I am actually checking all the elements in the `selectionsFromTable`  regardless of its position and index.

Comment: naming your list 'list' can cause some problems with python since list is also a built in function. also you seem to have too many ' , ' inside your dicts. (after the last element in each dict)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the example you have given, the following check would not work-

```
data['elements'] in selectionsFromTable
```

This is because, `selectionsFromTable` , contains `set` types, whereas `data['elements']` is a string . You want to check inside each element (set) in `selectionsFromTable` .

A simple way to do this -

```
arr = []
for data in list:
    elem = next((s for s in selectionsFromTable if data['elements'] in s), None)
    if elem:
        inner = []
        if 'Table' in elem:
            print("table")
            inner.append({'id': data['id'],
                          'section_title': data['elements'],
                          'tableorChart': data['table'],
                          })

        elif ('Bar' in elem) or ('Pie' in elem):
            print("chart")
            inner.append({'id': data['id'],
                          'section_title': data['elements'],
                          'tableorChart': data['chart'],
                          })

        arr.append(inner)
```

Main change would be the line -

```
elem = next((s for s in selectionsFromTable if data['elements'] in s), None)
```

What this does is that it either tries to take the first element in `selectionsFromTable` in which `data['elements']` , or if no such elements exists (that is the generator expression did not yield even a single value) , it returns `None` .

Then in next line we check if elem is not `None` and then do similar logic after that based on `elem` (not `selectionsFromTable` ).

Also, you should not used `list` as the name of a variable, it would end up masking the `list()` built-in function and you would not be able to use it afterwards in the same script.

---

Example/Demo -

```
>>> list = [{
...             'id': '1',
...             'elements': 'A',
...             'table': 'path/to/table1',
...             'chart': 'path/to/chart1',
...         },
...         {
...             'id': '2',
...             'elements': 'B',
...             'table': 'path/to/table2',
...             'chart': 'path/to/chart2',
...         },
...         {
...             'id': '3',
...             'elements': 'C',
...             'table': 'path/to/table3',
...             'chart': 'path/to/chart3',
...         },]
>>>
>>> selectionsFromTable = [{'A','2011','Table','Total'},
...                        {'C','2011','Bar','Total'},
...                        {'B','Pie','2001','Total'}]
>>> arr = []
>>> for data in list:
...     elem = next((s for s in selectionsFromTable if data['elements'] in s), None)
...     if elem:
...         inner = []
...         if 'Table' in elem:
...             print("table")
...             inner.append({'id': data['id'],
...                           'section_title': data['elements'],
...                           'tableorChart': data['table'],
...                           })
...         elif ('Bar' in elem) or ('Pie' in elem):
...             print("chart")
...             inner.append({'id': data['id'],
...                           'section_title': data['elements'],
...                           'tableorChart': data['chart'],
...                           })
...         arr.append(inner)
...
table
chart
chart
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(arr)
[[{'id': '1', 'section_title': 'A', 'tableorChart': 'path/to/table1'}],
 [{'id': '2', 'section_title': 'B', 'tableorChart': 'path/to/chart2'}],
 [{'id': '3', 'section_title': 'C', 'tableorChart': 'path/to/chart3'}]]
```